# jquery. $.post shows content of php file. Click on button in the php content start function defined in main file

Tags: php, jquery

For example file `main.php`

Here on document ready is function that includes content of another php file (named `include.php`).

This is content of `main.php`

```
(function(){
  $.post("include.php", function(show_some_content) {
  $('#id_show_some_conent').html(show_some_content);
  });
})();
```

Also some another jquery function

```
$(".click_to_test").click(function(){
alert('.click_to_test clicked.'); 
});
```

And then html

```
<div id="id_show_some_conent"></div>
```

As result in `id_show_some_conent` contains content of `include.php`

`include.php` contains

```
echo '<button id="some_id" class="click_to_test"> Click</button>';
```

So on document ready i see button Click. Expect, if i click on button, then `alert('.click_to_test clicked.');`. But no, does not work.

If in `include.php` paste `$(".click_to_test").click(function(){` then all works. How to get it to work if `$(".click_to_test").click(function(){` is only in `main.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try binding the click event within `$.post`:

```
(function(){
      $.post("include.php", function(show_some_content) {
      $('#id_show_some_conent').html(show_some_content);
      $(".click_to_test").bind('click',function(){
          alert('.click_to_test clicked.'); 
         });
      });

    })();
```

Comment: @user2118559 try this.

Comment: I am testing. It works. But also works modified example of CodingAnt. Seems the modified example would be more universal (and shorter). I will accept your answer, because it works without modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding , see if its working

```
$(".click_to_test").on('click',function(){
 alert('.click_to_test clicked.'); 
});
```

Comment: Now remember that Click button is rendered content. And for rendered content need to use something like `$(document).on('change', '.upper_level_id', function(){`. Your example should work, but it does not....

Comment: Seems works! Modified your example `$(document).on('click', '.click_to_test', function(){`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post("include.php", function(show_some_content) {
  $('#id_show_some_conent').html(show_some_content);
  });
}).on('click','.click_to_test',function(){
 alert('.click_to_test clicked.'); 
});
```

And if you want to add more events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.post("include.php", function(show_some_content) {
      $('#id_show_some_conent').html(show_some_content);
      });
 }).on('click','.click_to_test',function(){
        alert('.click_to_test clicked.'); 
 }).on('click','.someclass',function(){
        // type code here  
 });
// and so on
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!. But `.on('click','.click_to_test',function(){` is appended to `$(document).ready(function(){`. I want to include multiple functions in `$(document).ready(function(){`...

Comment: you can do that in the same way $(document).ready(function(){}.on('click','class',function(){}).on('click','class',function(){}) and so on add any number of functions you want.. sure it will work I tried that many times before .. by this way you make all your functions live without anything comes wrong in future

Comment: Thanks for advice. Will take into account. Sorry, accepted another answer. Your example also works, but to be true, the example is a bit longer and a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($){
  $.post("include.php", function(show_some_content) {
  $('#id_show_some_conent').html(show_some_content);
  });
 $(".click_to_test").on('click',function(){
     alert('.click_to_test clicked.'); 
   });
})(jQuery);
```

I hope this will do. Please let me know if it didnt work for you.

Comment: If i change '$(".click_to_test").on('click',function(){' to `$(document).on('click', '.click_to_test', function(){` then works. Thanks for advice.